How do I create a histogram with a variable stacked in groups (with ggplot2)?
I would like to make a histogram plot where the x-axis is Time (x=as.Date(seq(1,365),origin="2022-06-30")), and each bin has a different width because there are 13 samples with 13 different time periods within a year. The y-axis is the frequency of individuals (divided by area and days).
Each bin should then be subdivided in different groups of different species found in each sample, with each group stacked one on top of the other, and with different colors. The groups of species are the variables on the excel sheet below (Isopoda, Copepods...), and I would like to make them different levels of the same variable.
This is how the database looks like:
Excel database
Thank you.
I want to make something like this:
Example

Welcome to SO, Boh! Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., data.frame(...) or the output from dput(head(x))) directly into a [code block].

Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using dput(head(x)), data.frame(..), read.table(..), or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

When I want to learn how to do a new plot style, I often go to https://r-graph-gallery.com. It is a "picture menu" of sorts, showing many types of plots and variants within each, and it shows the data and code required to get that plot. It can be simpler to adapt their code to your data vice starting from scratch.

The type of plot you are interested in is not a histogram, but is more of column or bar chart.

Thank you, but how could I make a column or bar chart with varying bin width? And which one do you think is better?
